# Multiple Button have inside foreach loop but only first button can be clickable. How to make all the buttons can click?

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

```
<? foreach(.........){                      

<select id = "RelationshipSelect" name = 'RelationshipSelect' disabled>
                                //some codes implement                                                          
                        </select>`enter code here`

                        <input type = 'text' value = "<? echo ... ?>" id = "affectedSystems_0" name = 'affectedSystems_0' readonly> 

                                    <input type = "button" id = 'findAffectedSystems_0' value = 'Find' disabled>
                                        <input type = "button" id = 'removeAffectedSystems_0' value = 'Remove' disabled>


        <?}?>
```

[as showing in the photo, CI Relationship Field data are retrieve using foreach loop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWGkl.png)

In javascript file, I call the "findAffectedSystems_0" as find button id, but it only works on first row of "Find" button. How should I do to get all the buttons can be clickable.

```
document.getElementById("findAffectedSystems_0").addEventListener("click", function (){
              //some codes work

});
```

Comment: Make the ID of the buttons unique.

Comment: Find and Remove buttons can not have the same `id` for all. You need to make it dynamic like `findAffectedSystems_0` , `findAffectedSystems_1`

Comment: Thanks @JigarShah . but how I can do within the loop to get the dynamic id for buttons . Please help me , i m newbie in this

Comment: No! Assign a class to all buttons e.g. class="btn", then use document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: @A.S I have added sample code.

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) { // $variable should be array
        ?>
        <input type="button" class="common-class" name="findAffectedSystems_<?php echo $key ?>" id="findAffectedSystems_<?php echo $key ?>">
        <input type="button" class="common-class" name="removeAffectedSystems_<?php echo $key ?>" id="removeAffectedSystems_<?php echo $key ?>">
        <?php
    }
```

if you need separate action on each btn then go with id attribute otherwise for common action you should use class attribute

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: @P.Som please accept an an answer if you found this useful so question can be closed